# iptables on Windows10

Tags: linux, windows, networking, iptables

I'm looking for a way to get iptables functionality in windows 10. I enabled IP routing and I need to forward tcp data to another host (port 4000) and then forward his response while masquerading IP. In linux I was able to do this using the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4000 -m string --hex-string '|FF01|' --algo bm -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4000 -m string --hex-string '|1400|' --algo bm -j REJECT
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: What do those commands do?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SuperUser! Windows does not have an exact equivalent of `iptables`, so you will have to provide more detail. In particular, what is the goal of the commands you list? You mentionned forwarding and masquerading, but the commands are doing it at all. Also, why the hex string matching? [This may be an X Y Problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/335440)

Comment: Hello! thanks, what I need is to control the traffic of ip addresses that try to enter port 4000, if I block the hex string that I mentioned earlier, I can block those ip so they do not attack my port. If there is a program for windows that works the same, let me know. I hope it is understood, thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to block some specific IPs, can you explicitely state that in your question by [editing it](https://superuser.com/posts/1407489/edit)? Right now, you are asking how to perform traffic redirection and masquerading, which is an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Filtering Platform, upon which the Windows Firewall is built, does not (directly) support inspecting packet contents. As such, implementing this particular condition (`-m string --hex-string '|FF01|'`) is *not possible*.

To achieve this functionality, a so-called “Windows Filtering Platform Callout Driver” is necessary. As the name implies, these are a kernel-mode drivers. They can perform deep inspection of packet data and set actions like blocking a packet.

On 64-bit Windows, kernel drivers need to be code-signed.

You may also be able to achieve the same using a third-party firewall solution.

The simplest solution is to not use Windows though.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall has a similar style of rules to block certain IPs from entering on a port.

1. Open Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security. It should appear if you search Windows Firewall in the Start menu
2. From the left pane, select inbound rules
3. From the right pane, select New Rule
4. Rule Type: Choose Custom
5. Program: Choose All Programs
6. Protocol and Ports: Protocol Type is TCP, Local Port is Specific Port 4000. Remote port is unset.
7. Scope: Enter the IPs and Ranges you want to block. Note that LAN IPs go in the upper box. WAN IPs go in the lower box
8. Action: Block the connection
9. Profile: Select all options
10. Name: Set per your preferences. This has no effect on the rule.

Comment: Well and where do I have to put:-m string --hex-string '| FF01 |' - something bm -j DROP
Thank you!

Comment: You mentioned that your hex string was an IP address. Put the IP address in on the scope page, unencoded.